# Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit LTS TexLive 2014 Installation Problems

Tags: texlive, installing, texstudio, ubuntu

I installed TexLive 2014 from the `iso` image I downloaded from [TexLive images.](http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ctan/systems/texlive/Images/)The installation went on perfectly smooth and I also had the installer create `symlinks` inside `/usr/bin`. However, when I tried to install `TexStudio` the editor via the package manager `apt-get` Ubuntu also installed some older `TexLive` packages which I suspect that might have corrupted my original installation. How can I remove the older `TexLive` packages installed before installing `TexStudio` without affecting my original `TexLive 2014` installation? Furthermore, when I go into `/usr/bin` I noticed that one of the `symlinks` was broken, namely **mkluatexfontdb**, the output of `ll` command is as follows:

```
 ll mkluatexfontdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 55 Oca  2 22:27 mkluatexfontdb -> /usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/mkluatexfontdb
```

I checked in the directory pointed out by the link and confirmed that the file **mkluatexfontdb** did not exist. What can I do about it?

Comment: Don't install TeXstudio from the repositories. Download it from here: http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Sigur Unfortunately I installed it already would uninstalling everything related to `Tex` mess up with my original installation?

Comment: What is the result of `whereis texlive`?

Comment: `$ whereis texlive

texlive: /usr/local/texlive /usr/share/texlive` These are definitely not the directories I installed `TexLive2014` in.

Comment: TeXstudio has no relation with your TeXlive installation. You just need to point to the right path when configure TeXstudio so it will use the right executable.

Comment: @Sigur I checked the `symlinks` and they point to `Texlive2014` but one of them is broken and I do not know why. By the way due to `apt-get` package manager handling dependencies I get a lot of `tex` packages installed.

Comment: You can rerun `intall-tl.sh` and choose to install again the binaries.

Comment: @Sigur I double checked and this was my original directory for `TexLive2014` so I shall not reinstall it I guess?

Comment: When you install it from the iso the default directory is `/usr/local/texlive`.

Comment: @Sigur Okay I checked inside and everything is unmodified apart from that what about the broken link, I do not know the purpose of **mkluatexfontdb** even. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: From [TeX Live and Debian/Ubuntu](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html), "Integrating vanilla TeX Live with Debian", you may be able to use TeXstudio from Ubuntu with upstream TeX Live, but you'll have to use the `equivs` package to fool the Ubuntu package manager into thinking their TeX Live is installed. Or you could keep using the Ubuntu TL 2013 that came with 14.04. It's not horribly out of date, but that depends on what you really need.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Well I think fooling it is an option, if it is not too hard to achieve. By the way what about the broken link (actually the missing file from `/texlive/2014/bin`?

Comment: Using `apt` to uninstall the Debian TeXLive packages should not touch your manual install (unless things have changed recently).  I'd `purge` the install along with TeXStudio; then use the `tlmgr` utility to update (if needed) manual install; then set up the `equivs` as suggested; *then* install TeXStudio.  (Sadly, I can't help with the broken link: never heard of the 'file' before, and it doesn't seem to be present on my system [`tlmgr  revision 35841` using TeX Live 2014].)

Comment: @jon Thanks, I think following your suggestion I can manage to purge the `TexLive` packages and do an update with `tlmgr` to check everything is sound and up to date. I will install `TeXStudio` from the software center or .deb package not to mess the dependency issues the package manager arises. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @jon After searching for the package **mkluatexfontdb** I found the following link: http://ctan.localhost.net.ar/macros/luatex/generic/luaotfload/mkluatexfontdb.lua

Do you think downloading this file and saving it in the directory pointed at by the symlink will resolve the issue?

Comment: My guess is no: the version linked to claims it is synced to the version number of `luaotfload`, but your link has version 1.07, while the version from July of last year was 2.5.  Note also: if you want to install *any* TeX-related software from the software center or via `Apt`, you will need to use the `equivs` package to 'fool' your system to avoid having two TeX Live installs and to avoid having to subsequently manual 're-point' your software (e.g., editor or IDE) to the manual TeX Live install.  Setting up the `equivs` isn't that hard if you don't mind using the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here:

- you have put the symlink into `/usr/bin`, which is not a good idea, as this is a directory that is managed by dpkg/apt. You should have installed them into `/usr/local/bin` (etc) as suggested by the installer
- after that, you installed texstudio and by this the dependencies on texlive packages in Ubuntu. Since the Debian/Ubuntu packages also contain the same files in `/usr/bin`, all the smylinks are hosed. In particular, the link *targets* are overwritten with the version of binaries in the Debian/Ubuntu packages.

What you should do is:

- remove textudio, Debian/Ubuntu texlive packages, *and* your local TeX Live installation in `/usr/local/texlive`
- install again from the iso image, or better directly from the network installer, generating links into `/usr/local`
- use the equivs feature (see above comments) for building a texlive-local package, install that
- finally you can install all kind of programs from the Debian/Ubuntu repositories without having your installation hosed, and other texlive package installed.